# MongoDB distinct query against an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I have a schema similar to the following:

```
{
    "_id" : "12345",
    "_class" : "Refrigerator",
    "items" : {
        "APPLE" : {
            "id" : 123,
            "name" : "APPLE"
        },
        "BANANA" : {
            "id" : 234,
            "name" : "BANANA"
        },
        "STRAWBERRY" : {
            "id" : 345,
            "name" : "STRAWBERRY"
        }
    },
},
{
    "_id" : "23456",
    "_class" : "Pantry",
    "items" : {
        "CEREAL" : {
            "id" : 456,
            "name" : "CEREAL"
        }
    },
}
```

I want to get a list of distinct items where the _class=Refrigerator. The result should be `["APPLE","BANANA","STRAWBERRY"]`.
How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: It's better if you can store BSON in mongodb as `{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "APPLE"
    },
    {
      "id": 234,
      "name": "BANANA"
    },
    {
      "id": 345,
      "name": "STRAWBERRY"
    }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise aggregation operator `$objectToArray` ([SERVER-23310](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23310)) to turn keys into values. It should be able to group 'unknown' or 'dynamic' fields. This operator is available in MongoDB v3.4.4+

Given your example documents, you can use below [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{"class":"Refrigerator"}}, 
    {$project:{"items":{$objectToArray:"$items"}}}, 
    {$unwind:"$items"}, 
    {$group:{_id:"$_id", result:{$addToSet:"$items.k"}}}
])
```

See also the manual for: [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), and [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/)

If applicable for your use case, I would recommend to re-consider your [data schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) for easier access to the information that you're after. MongoDB has a flexible schema, you should use this for your application benefits.